# How to read from an external dictionary in LaTeX?

Tags: macros, external-files

I'm wondering how to define a LaTeX command `\x` that prints "def1" when I write `\x{name1}`, reading from an external (dictionary) file having a structure like

```
{name1}{def1}
{name2}{def2}
```

etc.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  I assume you meant `\x{name2}`, right? If so, please correct. I would have but just wanted to make sure.  Also, is modifying the external file an option?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the external file `dict.dat` is organized as

```
\entry{name1}{def1}
\entry{name2}{def2}
```

then

```
\newcommand{\entry}[2]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname entry@#1\endcsname{#2}}
\newcommand{\x}[1]{\csname entry@#1\endcsname}
\input{dict.dat}
```

will do what you're looking for.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! A big thank you Peter, for your prompt answer and for your corrections!

Comment: Perhaps adding error checking, such as `\expandafter\ifx\csname entry@#1\endcsname\relax\ERROR\else\csname entry@#1\endcsname\fi` would be nice.

Comment: @bblue: If this answers your question, you can check the ticker under the counter to accept it.